# Handling numerous lengthy text fields

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, varchar, page-size

I'm designing an SQL Server database that needs to have quite a few *(roughly 15)* long `varchar` fields, most of which I want to allocate a length of at least *1024 or 2048*.  Since this will obviously go well beyond the page size of *8060*, I realize the database will probably take a big performance hit any time this table is accessed.

I have also considered grouping these narratives into similar subjects and making *3 or 4 separate tables*, or just creating a single table with a `varchar(max)` field and an `int` representing the narrative type:

```
create table Narrative
(
  narrative varchar(max),
  narrativeType int
)
```

1. Will there be a significant performance hit with the original design?
2. What types of best practices may be used when dealing with large text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go ahead and split these narratives into their own table with a 1:1 relationship with the primary table.  I don't suspect I will ever be querying the values in these `varchar` fields, and there is no need to do any indexing on them.  Further, they will be accessed much less frequently than any of the other fields in the original table, so pulling them into a separate table helps focus the database design and may even improve performance, since they will only need to be dealt with when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim my answer to be the final word on the subject. Perhaps others could add to this.

You will not be able to build a clustered or non-clustered index on your `VARCHAR(MAX)` column because of it's size. This will make searches on your table quite slow.
However, you will be able to use [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which will benefit performance significantly.

Personally, I would not split the data up in to multiple tables if it can be avoided. The reason for this is that it makes querying homogeneous data troublesome.

In the case of `Full Text Search\Indexing`, you may be tempted to create multiple tables if your text is in multiple languages (FTS is language dependent). I've worked around this by creating multiple `Indexed Views` on my table and building Full Text Indexes on my `Indexed Views`

If you are expecting large volumes of data, you may want to consider [Partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

It would probably be best to read more about the topics and then further refine your question.